# Python cannot read text from an image [Python OCR with Tesseract]

Tags: python, python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this issue with reading exactly two lines of numbers (each line contains max of 3 digits) from an image.

My Python code has a big problem with reading a data from images like the ones below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Most of the times it is just printing random numbers.
What should I do to make this work?

This is my Python code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
from datetime import datetime
from pytesseract import pytesseract
import numpy as nm


pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'F:\\Tesseract\\tesseract'

while True:
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(515, 940, 560, 990))
    datetime = datetime.now()
    filename = 'pic_{}.{}.png'.format(datetime.strftime('%H%M_%S'), datetime.microsecond / 500000)

    gray = screenshot.convert('L')
    bw = nm.asarray(gray).copy()

    bw[bw < 160] = 0
    bw[bw >= 160] = 255

    convertedScreenshot = Image.fromarray(bw)

    tesseract = pytesseract.image_to_string(convertedScreenshot, config='digits --psm 6')

    convertedScreenshot.save(filename)

    print(tesseract)
```

*The image has to have white text on the black background or the black text on the white background.*

*It is also important to save the image afterwards.*

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract works best on images having black text on white Background. Invert the image before using tesseract by adding the below line :

```
 convertedScreenshot = 255 - convertedScreenshot
```

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was facing similar problem, I still am but using a few arguments in  'image_to_string' function helped.

I was using it for a single digit detection

> d = pytesseract.image_to_string(thr, lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem
> 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')

This helped me detect the single digits